# Extract URL for website background-image using BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the url for a "background-image" on a Soundcloud page (ex. https://soundcloud.com/ohwondermusic/drive). I'm not quite sure why I'm finding this so difficult compared to extracting urls from other webpages that I've found guides for online.

From the example webpage I linked, I would like this url: https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000125017075-di2n0i-t500x500.jpg that can be found by right clicking the album artwork and choosing 'inspect element' when in the Chrome browser.

I would like some way to consistently do this for other Soundcloud pages too (ie get the URL that would be found by inspecting the album artwork, the URL that ends in 500x500.jpg).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: I've used various codes to attempt to solve, along the lines of:

```
def pull2(url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    readOnly = soup.body.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'image readOnly customImage'})
    print readOnly.attrs['style']
```

or

```
def test(url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    imgs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"thumb-pic"})
    for img in imgs:
        print img.a['href'].split("imgurl=")[1]
```

Comment: Show us the code you attempted to solve this with already. What do you mean by finding it difficult, what kind of errors or issues is your current code resulting in?

Comment: @MichaelNeylon Hey Michael, the problem is usually that nothing gets printed when I would expect it to (ie I would think that I'm calling the right style to be printed but it's not printing).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should just be able to grab the style from the correct span on each page with something like:

```
soup.find("span", class_="sc-artwork")['style']
```

Then, write a regex to extract the url from that or split it on "url"

Comment: When I run this code (after: `[1] html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 [2] soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`, I get the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Yeah, I think if url is a string of a valid URL that should work, I'd probably need to see more of the code or the rest of that error traceback to know what's going wrong